# heteroscedasticity evaluation of residuals in linear LASSO regression model

Tags: regression, machine-learning, residuals, lasso, heteroscedasticity

I plotted residuals for linear LASSO model. Though tests for heteroscedasticity doesn't show any but i am seeing one some lines in residual plots depicting some heteroscedasticity might be present. I tried weighted least squares as well but its just moving the line up little bit. Any reccomendation on either transformation/how to remove this issue will be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Why are you looking at the residuals anyway? LASSO does not require homoscedasticity.

Answer (score 1):

LASSO is a method of variable selection and model building. Linear regression assumes homoscedasticity, so if you do LASSO for linear regression, you have that assumption.

Why not use a method that does not require the assumption, such as quantile regression?